# Super simple C# if/else syntax semantics, i.e. a great example of why you should use braces

Tags: c#

SE,

I'm used to Java syntax and have recently had to switch to C# at work. I'm a little confused on why a one of the if/then/else statements I've been writing haven't been working as expected, and was wondering if someone would be able to tell me a bit about the details of the syntax for why this isn't behaving as expected.

Take:

```
if (salePredicate != null)
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
else
    _sales.Add(s);
```

In this block, the `else` statement isn't reached when salePredicate is null. However,

```
if (salePredicate != null) {
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
} else
    _sales.Add(s);
```

will reach the `else` statement. Why isn't the first statement valid?

(P.S., I know the following is an option)

```
if (salePredicate == null ||
    salePredicate.Invoke(s))
    _sales.Add(s);
```

**Update**:
Statement 1 is really:

```
if (salePredicate != null)
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
    else
         _sales.Add(s);
```

Use braces, kiddos.

Comment: Probably doesn't help, but a great example of why you should use extra parenthesis to be clear instead of expecting people to remember rules that can be ambiguous.

Comment: Lesson learned… Brackets help.

Comment: If you find yourself commonly making mistakes like this, you might be interested to know that with the new compiler as a service (Roslyn) you can write checks for your code to highlight problems like this when they occur, and even provide the ability to fix it through a right mouse button option. Here's [one implementation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00655793-2f06-41fb-8eee-f68de3fa9a5d).

Comment: In common programmer parlance, these are parentheses: `()`, these are brackets: `[]`, and `{}` are called braces.  (Most programmers have adopted the American English names because most of the programming tools are made in the USA)

Comment: Updated just for you @BenVoigt

Comment: This is the problem with languages that ignore the indentation required for legibility: the braces get out of sync from the indentation. Braces are kind of an anachronistic legacy of C. Why keep reusing that part of C? It's probably time to let it go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the indentation is ignored. It sees the else as being paired with your nested if.

Comment: @JosephNields Is it different in Java? :)

Comment: Perhaps java's scoping for if/else works differently. I'm not really sure. I use braces in these situations if only to avoid confusion

Comment: It's the same in Java. I was just being dumb. :p

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is associating the `else` statement with the second `if` but what you really want is to have it associate with the first one.

```
if (salePredicate != null)
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
    else
        _sales.Add(s);
```

You can use braces to correct the problem:

```
if (salePredicate != null)
{
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
    {
       continue;
    }
}
else
{
    _sales.Add(s);
 }
```

It is because of this common pitfall that [many people](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no) recommend that you *always* use braces, even if they're gratuitous.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't the first statement valid?

Because the `else` refers to the second `if`, not the first one.  The whitespace that you've subtracted won't make any difference (since whitespace is not significant in this context), and is actually misleading, since it doesn't reflect the actual meaning of the code.

Most "best practice" practitioners will tell you that omitting the usual braces in this fashion is a bad practice, and this is one of the reasons why.

Answer (score 3):

C# is not python, the compiler doesn't look at your indentation to determine meaning.

You wrote

```
if (salePredicate != null)
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
else
    _sales.Add(s);
```

But the compiler treated it as

```
if (salePredicate != null)
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
    else
        _sales.Add(s);
```

You could have avoided that by "correct" usage of braces ("correct", because even if you memorize the syntax, other developers could get confused when reading your code.  *Always* use braces with nested if/else):

```
if (salePredicate != null) {
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
        continue;
}
else {
    _sales.Add(s);
}
```

Really, I am surprised you didn't run into this in Java as well, because the rules for if/else are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

An inner statement will only be evaluated if the outer statement evaluates to true.  In this case, second if and the else statements are both nested within the first if statement.  You don't have to... but I **highly** suggest you start using curly braces for your statements, to avoid confusion and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe The first block you mentioned, does not work the way you expected in java either.

The compiler will see that as:

```
if (salePredicate != null)
{
    if (!salePredicate.Invoke(s))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        _sales.Add(s);
    }
}
```

You need to explicitly put the blocks to prevent misunderstanding.